# Can I save custom aspect ratio settings on a per-file basis?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have some video files with distorted aspect ratios. With VLC I can modify the displayed ratio, but this setting is not saved, i.e. when I play a different file and return to the previous one, the original wrong ratio is restored.

Is it possible to save this setting on a per-file basis? Perhaps some meta data file for each media file?

Comment: VLC is terrible at saving things and I hate it for that. It can't even save equalizer controls *at all*; saving something per-file would be a miracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't save aspect ratios.

Using VLC, the only solution I can think of is to [transcode](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode) the video into the right aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

mplayer supports per file configuration files.